# MVP design pattern with winforms

Tags: winforms, mvp

I've recently started looking at using the MVP design pattern for writing winforms applications, and am a little stuck on how to structure some things. For example, I have an app that displays some records in a list; the user can then select from this list and click a "Copy" button, which copies files that relate to these records. For each file that's copied I need to write back to the database, updating the status of the record.

Seems simple, but on the one hand I (presumably) should keep the file copying logic in the form, and on the other hand I should have the call to update the database in the presenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you keep logic in the form? The form should contain as little logic as possible, and if it contains logic at all, it should only be logic related directly to the user interface. As copying files is **buniess logic**, it should not be performed in a view object.

Comment: Thanks. I've pretty much got it straight in my mind now, it just took a little bit of thought. I did work out how I can do this with the file copy logic in the form, but as you say, it is business logic.